# Enumerate forest trust relationships

Tags: windows, trust, domain

I'm trying to up my Windows domain enumeration game. I'm doing some exercises where I'm tasked to find the forest trust relationships without exploitation or creds or being on the domain.

All resources I've found seem to use Windows tools and imply that you're already on the domain.

How can I do this from an unauth perspective from a Linux box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BloodHound](https://github.com/BloodHoundAD/BloodHound) is a tool that includes PowerView to enumerate Active Directory trust relationships as well as every other entity type in an Active Directory: computers, sessions, users, groups, privileged users and groups, etc. It relies on PowerShell for its inputs, but the artifacts can still be gathered on Linux, macOS, and probably other OSes. Instead of text output or regular databases, BloodHound uses the Neo4j graph database to internally explain/explore the relationship mappings. It clearly shows domain relationships to forests as well as forests to other forests.

While it does technically require Domain Users rights, these can be gathered from another perspective, such as [chuckle](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2015/november/introducing-chuckle-and-the-importance-of-smb-signing/). Linux, like Windows, does not have to be on the domain to connect to assets of a Windows Server Domain (only the target domain and entity must be specified). Typically, one would connect with any smb or ntlm client software (again with the domain and entity, e.g., `MYDOMAIN\myusername`), but a permanent full-domain relationship (from boot) can be configured for Linux using [winbind](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Domain_Member), [sssd](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/04/02/sssd-vs-winbind/), [PowerBroker Open](http://www.powerbrokeropen.org), Likewise Software's Likewise Enterprise, Centrify DirectControl, Quest Authentication Services, and probably others. Only winbind and sssd are available as free, open-source software.

A quick way to see domain and forests (including correlation of trust relationships) with no authentication or exploitation -- assuming your Linux distro supports these packages -- is to install sssd with samba, samba-common, realmd, and adcli. If all are functional, then it may be as simple as (the braces `{}` denote that the arguments are optional, the brackets `[]` indicate that the arguments are required):

> realm discover *{--verbose} {--server-software=active-directory} {domainname or domain.com}*

If you know the domain name (or extract it from the above command when you don't know it), then you can run [adcli info](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_adcli_info) to get the closest domain controller, and then run adcli against the domain controller to [get the domain-forest](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA:Testcase_adcli_info_forest) info. Once the domain-forest name is known, you can run adcli again to get more information about that forest as well.

> adcli info *[domain or forest]*
>
> adcli info --domain-controller=*[dc.domain.example.com]*

Comment: If I understand correctly, all methods you've outlined require auth and creds? My exercise seems to imply this can be done without any form of authentication or exploitation. Also none of them allow null sessions. It's a flat network so I can nbtscan etc...

Comment: `realm discover` definitely does not require creds. chuckle does not require creds, but steals them